# Port communication using php

Tags: php, json

I want to know about port communication using php. To be precise, I have got a J son array from one receiver as

`{"MAC":"0xB4994C4AD521","RSSI":"66","UUID":"0xB9407F30F5F8466EAFF925556B57FE6D","Major":"54561","Minor":"58555"}{"RECEIVERMAC":"0xD3E455489120"}`

And my question is how to manage port communication with this details? kindly help me with php code.Besides have to draw a map using this details with port communication.

I hope you can understand my query please help with valuable suggestions.

Comment: what do you mean by 'manage'? what do you actually need to do? take a look in documentation of socket_create() http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php , but... you're talking about MAC level so I don't believe it will actually help, because at lease you need some IP to create some socket.

Comment: Can you give us a hint to the layer number in the network layer model where you want to achieve something?

Comment: Actually, I got this details from a receiver that I fixed inside a hospital or school, already got that details using node js that like json array but, I need those as a php code format instead of node js, then have to insert this into database and draw a map to know about the exact position of where that receivers placed. any hope..

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php